# Product of the entries in a row of Pascal's triangle

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, products

The **sum** of the $n$-th row in Pascal's triangle
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}
\end{equation}
has the well-known value of $2^n$. Now, I'm looking for the value of the **product** of the $n$-th row in Pascal's triangle, given through
\begin{equation}
s_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}.
\end{equation}
Any ideas how to calculate this value? Is it even possible?

I found some papers (e.g. [Finding e in Pascals Triangle](http://www.brotherstechnology.com/docs/Finding_e_in_Pascals_Triangle.pdf)) dealing with the growth of this sequence, and it seems to be that the ratio of the ratios $\frac{s_{n+1}/s_n}{s_n/s_{n-1}}$ has the limiting value of 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{s_{n+1}s_{n-1}}{(s_n)^2}=e.
\end{equation}
Is this helpful for calculating the value of $s_n$? So far, it is not clear to me how the growth rate of a sequence relate to its value.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [OEIS A001142](http://oeis.org/A001142) which begins $$1, 1, 2, 9, 96, 2500, 162000, 26471025, 11014635520, 11759522374656, 32406091200000000, 231627686043080250000, 4311500661703860387840000, 209706417310526095716965894400, 26729809777664965932590782608648192$$  An approximate formula is given
$a(n) \approx A^2 * \exp(n^2/2 + n - 1/12) / (n^{(n/2 + 1/3)} * (2*\pi)^{((n+1)/2))}$, where $A = A074962 = 1.2824271291\ldots$ is the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant.

The growth rate is dominated by the term
$$\frac{\exp(\frac {n^2}2)}{n^{\frac n2}}=\exp \left( \frac{n^2}2-\frac n2\log n \right)$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: If the growth is dominated by $\exp(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\log{}n)$, is it equivalent to say that $a(n)\in\mathcal{O}(\exp(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\log{}n))$?

Comment: @MaxWell:  No.  Big-O requires you be within a constant factor.  The next term here is a factor $(2\pi)^{(n+1)/2}$, which is not constant.  Big-O is hard for complicated fast-growing things like this.  I found the first couple terms and stopped.

Comment: One "cute" way to express growth rates like this is, for example, $a(n) = \exp(n^2 /2 - O(n\log n))$

Answer (score 3):

The closest I came to tackling this problem was through a recursive definition of the function.

Consider expanding the function

$$
\begin{equation}
s_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}.
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
s_n=\binom{n}{0}.\binom{n}{1}.\binom{n}{2}...\binom{n}{n}
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
s_n=\frac{n!}{(n-0)!(0)!}\times\frac{n!}{(n-1)!(1)!}\times\frac{n!}{(n-2)!(2)!}\times...\times\frac{n!}{(n-n)!(n)!}
\end{equation}
$$

There are $(n + 1)$ terms in this expansion. The product can also be written like this:

$$
\begin{equation}
s_n= \frac{n! \times n! \times n! \times ...\times n! }{{\Big( (n-0)! \times (n-1)! \times ... \times (1)! \times (0)!\Big) \times \Big( (0)! \times (1)! \times ... \times (n-1)! \times (n)!\Big)}}
\end{equation}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
s_n= \frac{(n!)  ^ {n + 1}}{{( 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times... \times n!) ^ 2 }}
\end{equation}
$$

Similarly,

$$
\begin{equation}
s_{n+1}= \frac{\big((n+1)!\big)  ^ {n + 2}}{{( 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times... \times (n+1)!) ^ 2 }}
\end{equation}
$$
Simplifying the numerator and the denominator we get,
$$
\begin{equation}
\big((n+1)!\big)  ^ {n + 2} = (n+1)! \times \big( (n+1)! \big)^{n+2} = (n+1)! \times (n+1)^{n+1} \times ( n!)^{n+1}
\end{equation}
$$

And,

$$
\begin{equation}
( 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times... \times (n+1)!) ^ 2 = \big((n+1)!\big)^2 \times ( 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times... \times n!) ^ 2
\end{equation}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{equation}
s_{n+1}= \frac{(n+1)! \times (n+1)^{n+1} \times ( n!)^{n+1}}{\big((n+1)!\big)^2 \times ( 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times... \times n!) ^ 2}
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
s_{n+1}= \frac{(n+1)! \times (n+1)^{n+1}}{\big((n+1)!\big)^2 }
\end{equation} \times \frac{( n!)^{n+1}}{( 1! \times 2! \times 3! \times... \times n!) ^ 2}
$$

$$
\begin{equation}
s_{n+1} = \frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)! } \times s_n
\end{equation} 
$$

I am unsure if this could be simplified further, or if there is a relation that does not use the factorial.

Comment: Using Stirling's approximation the multiplier is about $e^{n+1}/\sqrt{2 \pi (n+1)}$